# How can I relate a cdk drag item into a list of cdk drop list?

Tags: angular, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I want to build a simple drag and drop game using `@angular/cdk/drag-drop` module, I have some drop zones and a draggable item that the player should choose the correct drop zone and drag the item to it.
my problem is I can't bind my custom data objects to drop zone lists.

here is my project on stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-42drhc?devtoolsheight=33

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `@angular/cdk/drag-drop` you can only drag items [between lists](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#transferring-items-between-lists) in fact you have to add a `div`  with`cdkDropList` around your player item like you have done it the other zones.